# DI not resolving base Interface from sub-Interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a rather simple setup for a repository design. Using DI to resolve repositories in controller constructors.

However DI is behaving rather strangely. It appears to be unable to resolve a dependency which is resolved as the base of a registered interface. I believe it should be able to do this as any type that satisfies the sub-interface must also satisfy the base.

Interested to know if anyone knows why this may be happening?

Example:

**Base Interface**

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T>
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

**Sub Interface**

```
public interface IReadWriteRepository<T> : IReadOnlyRepository<T>
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class AccountRepository: IReadWriteRepository<Account>
{
    public void DoSomething() { /* BLAH */ }
    public void DoSomethingElse() { /* BLAH */ }
}
```

**Registration**

```
services.AddTransient<IReadWriteRepository<Account>, AccountRepository>();
```

**Resolution**

```
provider.Resolve<IReadWriteRepository<Account>>(); // SUCCEEDS :)
provider.Resolve<IReadOnlyRepository<Account>>(); // FAILS! :(
```

Comment: Services is simple dictionary - with abstraction types as keys, you need explicitly register another abstraction to add it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how dependency injection works. If you want `IReadOnlyRepository<Account>` to resolve to `AccountRepository` you will have to register that, too.

```
services.AddTransient<IReadOnlyRepository<Account>, AccountRepository>();
```

Otherwise, how would the DI container know what to generate. Imagine what you have in mind would actually work, what would happen if you would ask it to resolve `IDisposable` or `IEnumerable`? It cannot magically know what you need, you have to be explicit.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. If you asked for `IDisposable` or `IEumerable` and you had multiple things registered that satisfied this resolution I would expect that to fail but in this instance it is possible for DI to resolve this.

Comment: Do you have any documentation of this? I couldn't find anything referencing this issue. Hence why I created the question.

Comment: @GerardWilkinson It's possible... but the DI is not build on the fact that in your exceptional case it might be possible. Generally speaking it would be a confusing nightmare to have DI resolve to a type it has to figure out itself. DI has nothing to do with the type system or inheritance. It's a simple lookup. Is the type you need registered. Great. Is it not? Error.

Comment: It wouldn't really be a confusing nightmare. It's how it should be written, you have an rather simple inheritance tree to navigate. This is not an exceptional case either. Perfectly reasonable to have read and write separated to clearly demark no editing from this place in the code...

Comment: Well, I guess you are free to write this simple little thing yourself then... should not be too hard :)

Comment: It's also perfectly reasonable to just register your class for both interfaces. It's not either or. Just register for both.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I was mainly just interested as to why this wouldn't work. There isn't anything wrong with registering it twice just that it can already do it if the DI was built properly.